# Web Caching using the SQUID Proxy Server

Tags: centos, fedora

[enter image description here][1]

file:///C:/Users/moham/Downloads/Documents/IT3010_LabSheet07.pdf
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe5iS.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.